# Problem with staying or problem about staying?

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

1. Do you have any problem *with* my staying here?
2. Do you have any problem *about* my staying here?

Comment: I'd say _Do you have any problem with me staying here?_ -- using _my_ makes it sound rather awkward. And _problem_ is usually followed by _with_.